# partial differential equations with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

hi,

does anyone know some good references (books, papers) on partial differential equations with mixed boundary conditions ?

actually I am intrested in the following: Let $f(x)=(f_{1}(x),...,f_{n}(x))$ such that $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an unknown function and denote by $J(f)$ the Jacobian of $f$. There is a first order partial non-linear equation, where $f$ is the unknown function, i.e. $F(J(f)(x),f(x),x)=g(x)$ (where one can assume that $F$ is "nice" and $g$ is some given "nice" function) on a domain $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\partial D=C_{1} \cup C_{2}$. And the boundary conditions are: $f$ restricted to $C_{1}$ is zero and $J(f)$ restricted to $C_{2}$ is zero (as a matrix). Are there some references on such kind of equations ?

Does anyone have an idea, about some references or this is to be solved ???

pascal

Comment: Yes, I do......


Comment: What do you mean by mixed boundary conditions?

Comment: Your question is far to vague. Can you specify what you are interested in?

Comment: actually I am intrested in the following: Let $f(x) = (f_{1}(x), ..., f_{n}(x))$ such that $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an unknown function and denote by $J(f)$ the Jacobian of $f$. There is a first order partial non-linear equation, where $f$ is the unknown function, i.e. $F(J(f)(x), f(x), x) = g(x)$ (where one can assume that $F$ is "nice" and $g$ is some given "nice" function) on a domain $D$ such that $\partial D = C_{1} \cup C_{2}$. And the boundary conditions are: $f|_{C_{1}} = 0$ and $J(f)|_{C_{2}} = 0$. Are there some references on such kind of equations ? 

Comment: I think it should be clear now, what I mean ? Or ?

Comment: To have $J(f)$ vanish completely seems a bit strong to me, at least if your equation is elliptic, you'd be almost prescribing both Neumann and Dirichlet at the same time (if $J(f)|_{C_2} = 0$ you must have $f$ is constant on $C_2$ if the boundary is sufficiently smooth). If this is indeed the case you are interested in, you may want to look into the literature on partially overdetermined boundary value problem. But to my knowledge much of the recent development in that field is for the semilinear equation $\triangle f + N(f,\nabla f)$ and not first order systems or quasilinear equations.

Comment: Is it possible for you to write down $F$ and/or characterize it somewhat?

Comment: $F$ is the determinat function: $F(J(f)(x), f(x), x) = det((a_{ij}(x))_{ij} + J(f)(x))$, where $a_{ij}(x)$ are some given analytic functions (hence very smooth). 

Comment: could one do something (by this i mean some transformations) to make it work ?


Comment: If you assume that $f = \nabla h$ for some scalar function $h$ (an assumption that may or may not be justified), the expression $F(J(f),f,x) = F(D^2 h, Dh, x)$ is actually of Monge Ampere type. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation This makes it elliptic and something like what I said in my first comment applies. I am not familiar enough with the literature, but you should take a look for stuff on "partially overdetermined boundary value problem" for "monge-ampere" or "fully nonlinear elliptic" equations. 

Comment: Do you mean the partial differential equation like the Tricomi equation?

Comment: From the comments, the equation is fully nonlinear. So no, I don't think it is like the Tricomi equation.

Comment: Sorry because I know little about it,and I'm also looking for some reference about the topic.Do you have any to recommend? Why can't I give a boudary condition of mixed type to a fully nonlinear equation?What if I make a Legendre transformation?